# Display details from the grid when button is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview which consist the details of people,
and also I have a Textbox and search button,in which when i enter the name of a particular person
it should display his own details along with the header from thr grid view.

Here is my code..

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ENTERKEY001;Initial Catalog=ThirdJanuaryDb;Integrated Security=True");//DataBase Connection

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "SearchSp";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text.Trim();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        GridView1.DataBind();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();      
}
```

Kindly help me...

Comment: _Well_, what is the problem exactly then? You get any error or exception message? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: my code is...  con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SearchSp";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text.Trim();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "ss");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ss"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

Comment: my error is ..Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things wrong.

- You execute your query with `ExecuteNonQuery` after you bind your gridview. Actually, you don't bind *anything at all*. And you don't need `ExecuteNonQuery` here since I think your stored procedure returns some data instead of just executing.
- Use `ExecuteReader` to get all values and assign it to your `DataSource` property.

---

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = dr;
GridView1.DataValueField = "someColumn";
GridView1.DataTextField = "someColumn";
GridView1.DataBind();
```

- Use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` as a best practice.

---

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CnnStr))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "SearchSp";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text.Trim();
    using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       GridView1.DataSource = dr;
       GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: placing the above code it gives a red underline mark on "DataValueField" and "DataTextField"

Comment: @AdhithAshok Deleted them.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use data adapter but here's the fixed code, it should work like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ENTERKEY001;Initial Catalog=ThirdJanuaryDb;Integrated Security=True");//DataBase Connection
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SearchSp";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: placing the above code it gives me an error message telling"Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition."

Comment: It means that there is an already existing column that is conflicting with the data. Check the grid view.

Comment: It isn't giving me an error it just blinks and nothing could be seen on the grid

Comment: you could give me a sample result of the stored procedure and I will modify the code to use a datareader, which is the proper way to read from the database.

Comment: There are two tables "ThirdJanuaryTable" and "SixthJanuaryTable" ALTER procedure [dbo].[SearchSp]
@NAME varchar(255)
as
begin
select ThirdJanuaryTable.NAME,ThirdJanuaryTable.ID,ThirdJanuaryTable.ADDRESS,ThirdJanuaryTable.GENDER,SixthJanuaryTable.MOBILENO from ThirdJanuaryTable,SixthJanuaryTable where NAME=@NAME
end

Comment: ThirdJanuaryTable consist NAME,ID,ADDRESS,GENDER:  SixthJanuaryTable consist ID,MOBILENO: in both the tables ID is set as primary key